# javadoc MyClass.java formatting errors

Tags: java, javadoc

I'm trying to create an HTML interface for my class, but I've got some errors related with `<` and `>` format I think. I'm on Fedora 28 with java 1.8.0_191.

I wrote `javadoc MyStringVector.java` and get these errors:

`MyStringVector.java:53: error: malformed HTML
       if 0 <= index <= size(), insert the item specified in the location`

`MyStringVector.java:57: error: malformed HTML
       if index < 0 o index > size() returns without do nothing`

`MyStringVector.java:107: error: malformed HTML
      if 0 <= index < size(), removes the element at the specified index,`

`MyStringVector.java:189: error: malformed HTML
      if index < 0 o index >=size() returns null.`

If its a formatting problem, what escape sequence I have to use? Thanks!

Comment: javaodoc is  HTML. Use `&lt;` instead of `<`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just escape the `>` and `<` characters like this :

```
  if 0 &lt;= index &lt;= size()
```

or

```
  if index &lt; 0 o index &gt; size()
```

And so on for all the symbols that are reserved for `xml/html` formatting.

Comment: Or you can use the [`@literal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html#CHDCFJDG) or [`@code`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html#CHDFHHBB) tag